# Adding a link to my image is affecting the styling

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to make an image a link that users can click on, however every time I add the link to my html it messes up the styling of my page.

This is the code that's messing up my page:

```
    <ul class="portfolio">
<li class="project option-1">
  <div class="project-image"><a href="default.asp"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/sports/1/" alt="Sports Image" /></div>
  <div class="project-info">
    <h2 class="project-info-title">Cricket Journey</h2>
  </div>
</li>
```

*As soon as I remove the href before the img src, my page goes back to looking normal*

Why is this messing up the style of my page? The code seems to look fine. Thanks in advance for the help!

EDIT
*CSS*

```
    .portfolio {
display: flex;
flex-flow: row wrap;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
list-style: none;
}

.project {
position: relative;
flex: 1 0 calc(100% - 20px);
margin: 10px;

&:hover {
    .project-info {
    }
}

@media (min-width: 520px) {
    flex: 0 0 calc((100% / 2) - 20px);
}

@media (min-width: 860px) {
    flex: 0 0 calc((100% / 3) - 20px);
}
}

.project-image img {
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Please include the relevant CSS.

Comment: We don't know what you're seeing without a [mcve] which would include your CSS. What does it look like now and what should it look like?

Comment: You're missing the closing anchor tag

Comment: and add li{list-style-type:none},not sure what exactly you want but  your markup does not break

Comment: close your anchor tag...How should it look

Comment: @Geeky worked. thanks a lot, its always the small errors!